# How to insert stock quantity and update into another table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update the quantity of stock when a new stock is added. I'm using array because I want to add more than one product in the page. But the data is not insert into the db and no update on the quantity of stock too. What do I miss on this code?

```
 <?php
include 'db_connection.php';

    if(isset($_POST["submit4"])){


        foreach($_POST['fk_product'] as $index => $searchid){

            $sql="INSERT INTO supplier (supplier_name, date_in, fk_product, quantity_in) VALUES ('".$_POST['supplier_name']."','".$_POST['date_in']."','".$_POST['fk_product'][$index]."', '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."')"; 

            $quantity_bal=$_POST['quantity_bal'];

            if($quantity_bal==0){
            $sql="UPDATE product set quantity_bal= quantity_ori + '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."' WHERE id_produk = '".$_GET['id']."'";
            }else if($quantity_bal!=0){
            $sql="UPDATE product set quantity_bal= quantity_bal + '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."' WHERE id_produk = '".$_GET['id']."'";

            }

            $query = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql);
    if($query){
        header("location:product.php");
    }



    }      
        }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you're missing is that you need to concatenate the queries, with the use of `=` assignment operator, you've just overridden the former string, so it should be like this

```
foreach($_POST['fk_product'] as $index => $searchid){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO supplier (supplier_name, date_in, fk_product, quantity_in) VALUES ('".$_POST['supplier_name']."','".$_POST['date_in']."','".$_POST['fk_product'][$index]."', '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."')"; 

        $quantity_bal = $_POST['quantity_bal'];

        if($quantity_bal == 0){
            //I'm presuming that the quantity_ori is a variable here 'coz you're trying to sum up with the original to the latest one
            $sql .= "UPDATE product set quantity_bal= $quantity_ori + '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."' WHERE id_produk = '".$_GET['id']."'";
        }else if($quantity_bal != 0){
            $sql .= "UPDATE product set quantity_bal= $quantity_bal + '".$_POST["quantity_in"][$index]."' WHERE id_produk = '".$_GET['id']."'";
        }

}
```

We changed the `=` symbol in your update queries into `.=` and then your `quantity_ori` earlier doesn't have the `$` symbol, since we're presuming it's a variable, don't forget the `$`

Comment: @Dharman according to what he was asking, he wants to do the **INSERT** and **UPDATE** at the same time, that's why he used the function `mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql);` and according to the documentation of  `mysqli_multi_query()`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php, strings should be concatenated, makes sense now?

Comment: Ok, my bad. There is no semicolon at the end which led me to believe you are trying to make query out of two.

Comment: hello @marmar, have you tried it and is it working?

Comment: @JueViole17 i made some modification on the code and it finally works! thank you for the help!